# Running Google Now on Pi - possible? Or use Windows 10 Cortana?

Tags: wifi, windows, android, windows-iot

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and I was just wondering if it's possible to run Google Now using one. I was hoping to put a Raspberry Pi (with WiFi, a microphone and speaker) in a case and have Google Now running live in my kitchen so I can ask it for recipes, to add stuff to shopping lists, measurement conversions etc. - maybe even play music.

If it's not possible to run Android or any iteration of Google Now using the Pi, then I heard that the new version of Raspberry Pi comes with Windows 10, does that mean it will come with Cortana already on it? Maybe that's possible? I'd prefer Google Now but Cortana would be a decent backup plan.

Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google Now is specific to android.  The only API I can find for it is if you want to create custom cards for it to display in the user center.  As far as I know, there is currently no Android image for the RPi that is really usable.

While Windows 10 is coming to the RPi, it will most likely not have Cortana.  The RPi version of Win10 is definitely geared to be used as an IOT (internet of things) device.  I can't imagine Cortana would be particularly useful on the RPi (even the 2's) limited hardware.